# Redmine without e-mail functionality

Tags: email, redmine, internet

I want to install [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) on an air-gapped network. It has no connection to the internet or any other network. As it doesn't need an e-mail server, it doesn't have that either.

My question is, can Redmine work without e-mail functionality?

Technically I could install an e-mail server on the network but I have no permission for that and I don't want to either, as its only purpose would be Redmine and not e-mail functionality in itself.

From the User Guide I would initially conclude 'no' because I can't find it in either the requirements or optional components. However in the configuration it mentions e-mail.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can work without an smtp server, you'll be just missing the mail functionnalities (tracking updates notifications, etc, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be like that but I needed to be sure I didn't overlook anything. This is the first time I'm installing such software.

Answer (score 2):

In the worst case, use the "sendmail" mail transport and install a fake sendmail binary that just discards mail.

Comment: Good one. I'll keep that in mind in case Redmine does something like giving error messages. As I said above, we already have Flyspray but I didn't install that.